# How can I map the results of raw query to datatable using EntityFramework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, datatable

I have a need to run raw queries on a database. These tables do not have Model classes in my project to map the result onto.

So I want to be able to execute any select query using `context.Database
SqlQuery` but instead of mapping it a model class, I want to be able to map it to a generic solution like `datatable` or `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`.

Is it possible to do such a thing in EntityFramework 6?

I know I can use `SqlDataAdapter` to execute raw query and map the data to a datatable. I am just looking for a way to do the something with Entity.

Comment: So you want to use the result of a `context.Database.SqlQuery<>()` and then save it with entity ? You just have to specify the right type in `<>`

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I want to either specify `datatable` or `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` somehow. For example `SqlQuery<datatable>`

Comment: Hooooo, i would have suggested you get the return of 'SqlQuery<ClassYouMade>' in an object you created and then turn it into a dictionary programmaticaly : it could have been done easily in a partial class of your entity. But you want to do both action all at once... more complicated

Comment: Like I stated in my question, I don't have Model class for my tables. which is why I want to be able to map the data to `datatable` or list of dictionaries